# $(X,d_X), (Y,d_Y)$ : Metric space, $(X,T(d_X)), (Y,T(d_Y))$ : Topological space, $\ T(d_{X×Y})⊆T(d_1),\ T(d_{X×Y})⊇T(d_1)$

Tags: general-topology

$(X,d_X), (Y,d_Y)$ : Metric space, $(X,T(d_X)), (Y,T(d_Y))$ : Topological space

$\forall(x,y),(x', y')∈X×Y \ :$

$\qquad d_{X×Y}$(on $X×Y) :=\sqrt {d_X(x,x')^2+d_Y(y,y')^2}$

$\qquad d_1$(on $X×Y):= d_X(x,x')+d_Y(y,y') $

Then, $\ T(d_{X×Y})⊆T(d_1),\ T(d_{X×Y})⊇T(d_1)$

---

Pf )

(i)"⊆" Take  $\forall O∈T(d_{X×Y}), \forall (x,y)∈O,\forall O'∈T(d_1) $

Then, $\existsε>0\ s.t. \ u(X×Y, d_{X×Y},(x,y),ε)⊆O, \existsε>0\ s.t. \ u(X×Y, d_1,(x,y),ε)⊆O'$

And Take $\forall x'∈u(X, d_X,x,\frac{\epsilon}{2}),\  \forall y'∈u(Y, d_y,y,\frac{\epsilon}{2})$

Then, $\ d_X(x,x')<\frac{\epsilon}{2},\ d_Y(y,y')<\frac{\epsilon}{2} \Rightarrow d_{X×Y}((x,y),(x',y')) = \sqrt{d_X(x,x')^2+d_Y(y,y')^2}<d_X(x,x')+d_Y(y,y')=d_1((x, y),(x',y')) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$

So,$\ u(X×Y, d_{X×Y},(x,y),ε)⊆ u(X×Y, d_1,(x,y),ε)⊆O'$

Therefore,$\ (x,y)∈T(d_1)$

Finally, $T(d_{X×Y})⊆T(d_1)$

(ii)"⊇"

---

Is this proof correct?

And how should I prove the opposition($T(d_{X×Y})⊇T(d_1)$)?

Comment: Please fix the title.

Comment: This is difficult to read and the statement you are proving is not clear. Please try to write out full sentences in the statement, and only put mathematical phrases in latex (dollar signs), not words.

Comment: Sorry, There were some mistakes, so I corrected them. Please let me know if there is any place to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$d^2_{X \times Y} \le d_1^2$ (for all points) because of the inequality of reals $a^2 + b^2 \le (a+b)^2$.

So taking roots

$$\forall x,x' \in X, y,y\in Y: d_{X \times Y}((x,y),(x',y')) \le d_1 ((x,y),(x',y'))$$

Also $a = \sqrt{a^2} \le \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ for all $a,b \ge 0$ in $\Bbb R$ so it follows from that plus the same fact for $b$ as well, that:

$$\forall x,x' \in X, y,y\in Y: d_1((x,y),(x',y')) \le 2 d_{X \times Y}((x,y),(x',y'))$$

and so inside each ball of one metric we always have a ball of the same centre in the other metric and vice versa, which implies their topologies are the same.